# Calling Highcharts within a function

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to call a function which contains the code to build a Highcharts chart but I am being thrown the error.

```
TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function    

data: (function() {
```

I have ensured highcharts.js is being called before I am trying to build the chart.

If I remove the function and just have it in my code as normal then the chart builds fine but the data I want on the chart hasn't had time to be fetched and so is not loaded into the graph. Therefore, I am using setTimeout() to wait for the data to be fetched before the chart is loaded but the chart now does not load.

```
webiopi().callMacro("getTempHist", [], arrayTemp);
    function arrayTemp(macro, args, data) {
        testlist = data.split(" ");

        $(document).ready(function() {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
            });

            var chart;
            $('#temptracker').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                load: function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Number(temp0);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 60000);
                }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live Temperature'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 100
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                text: 'Temperature'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
                }],
                min: -10,
                max: 45,
                startOnTick: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', this.x) +'<br/>'+ 
                    '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '°C' + '</b>';
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Temperature',
                data: (function() {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
                    data.push({
                    x: time + ((i-19) * 1000),
                    y: Number(testlist[i])
                    });
                }
                return data;
                })()
            }]
            });
        });
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you provide full code? I think that you should create chart in callback where you are fetching your data.

Comment: For me it works properly, http://jsfiddle.net/8hMze/1/ (I advice to remove double document.ready)

Comment: I have edited the question to include full code. I did what Pawel suggested and created the chart in the callback but I am still being thrown the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove inline code where you create data array, and just define before creating chart another variable, which will contain data. Something like this:

```
webiopi().callMacro("getTempHist", [], arrayTemp);
function arrayTemp(macro, args, data) {
    testlist = data.split(" ");
    // generate an array of random data
    var data = [],
        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 19; i++) {
        data.push({
            x: time + ((i-19) * 1000),
            y: Number(testlist[i])
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#temptracker').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
            load: function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Number(temp0);
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 60000);
            }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live Temperature'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 100
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
            },
            plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
            }],
            min: -10,
            max: 45,
            startOnTick: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M', this.x) +'<br/>'+ 
                '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + '°C' + '</b>';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: data
        }]
        });
    });
}
```

If you still have error, make sure you have 3.x+ version of Highcharts.

Comment: Still throwing the same error with that change. I have tried with both fetching my local version of Highcharts v3.0.9 and fetching Highcharts straight from the web but again this made no difference.

Comment: Good, then you have three ways only: a) you have some typo in your JS code - use jsLint to make sure it's fine. b) you have wrong path to jQuery, or have included jQuery before Highcharts. c) you are calling $(..).highcharts() before Highcharts are included.

Comment: I have looked at my code in jsLint but can't see anything wrong with it. I am also including highcharts.js before I am calling it. I thought jQuery was meant to be included before you include Highcharts? Either way, I have tried both but neither seems to work. The only problem seems to be because Highcharts is inside a function but I don't know how I can get around this.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say that jQuery have to be loaded before Highcharts. Can I see it live somewhere?  Also try to call `webiopi().callMacro("getTempHist", [], arrayTemp);` after document is ready.

Comment: You need to call Jquery file before calling highchart.js . If you are not getting the point, i will write down the code!